# install the updates of the setup on the actual setup location

Tags: installation, inno-setup, setuptools

I have installed a java application and i want to reinstall the new updates on the same location. but i am unable to read the location where the software is being installed .

```
I want if the full application is being installed in d:/program files then
   the new setup    should also be installed to the same location
```

Comment: It this is Inno Setup based install script, then just use same `AppId` - by default `AppId` is same as `AppName`. If your update will have same `AppId` as the main installer, it will read app location.

Comment: i am using inno setup for this , i m not expert for writing the script.

Comment: It's also possible to use the same installer for performing both updates and original installs -- this is typically the best idea for small applications.  You can use `DisableDirPage=auto` and `DisableProgramGroupPage=auto` to help with this; you need not do anything else special at all, normally, but you may want to add some code that uses `GetVersionNumbers` to detect the current version (if any) and prevent accidental downgrades.  Finally, note that you can use `WizardForm.PrevAppDir` to both detect a previous installation and get its `{app}` path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main application install script

```
[Setup]
AppId=MyMainApplicationId
AppName=MyApplicationName
AppVersion=MyApplicationVersion
```

Update install script

```
[Setup]
AppId=MyMainApplicationId
AppName=MyUpdateName
AppVersion=MyUpdateVersion
```

As both installscripts have the very same `AppId`, the update will use same dir as Main App. But... You should implement check that will look up if the Main Application is installed. 
You can try to place this `[Code]` in Update Install Script:

```
[Code]
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  if RegValueExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyMainApplicationId_is1',
'UninstallString') then 
    begin
      Result := True;
    end
    else begin
      MsgBox('Main Application was not found!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
end;
```